# Не добавляются данные в таблицу БД. (PyMySQL)

Tags: mysql, python

Делал все через Python 3.5 в связке с PyMySQL. Таблица вроде созданна, все работает. Сервер с MySQL держу локально. PHP замечательно с ней работает, а вот Python не хочет добавлять данные. 
Код:

```
# Предположим что login = 'Test', а passw = 'Coffee'
con = sql.connect(db='testdb', user='root', passwd='', host='127.0.0.1')
cur = con.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('{}','{}');".format(login,passw)
cur.execute(query)
con.close()
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка? Или это где-то на стороне MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работал с PyMySQL, но полагаю он работает точно так же как и psycopg2 (драйвер PostgreSQL).
У вас не хватает строки

```
conn.commit()
```

Она должна идти после

```
cur.execute(query)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь работает!